# Android Toast to show on previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, toast

in my android app, I have a button that leads to an activity which in some cases, does not launch because of an if statement.

What happens, is I kill the activity with `.finish();` on the onCreate, so nothing happens when the user taps the button.

But I would like to display an alert, a Toast, to the user on the current activity. Not sure if this is really clear, but here's what should basically happen:

- User is on homepage
- User click button to go to next activity
- Nothing happens because the activity is killed with the `.finish();` on the onCreate.
- Here, a toast notification should be displayed on the homepage after the user clicked the button

Here's my code so far :

```
try {
        this.storeMarkerList = new StoreMarkerList(this.mapView);
        StoreList list = (StoreList)getBaseApplication().getSessionParameter("selected.storelist", null);
        if (list == null || list.size() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(???, "No stores", 5000);
            this.finish();  
        }
        else {
```

(...)

Comment: why not just use `Toast.makeText(this, "No stores", 5000).show();`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No stores", 5000).show();
```

Comment: **getApplicationContext()**  ;-) tks

Comment: Obvious but it was killing me :)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the elusive [`#show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show%28%29) call after `Toast.makeText()`.

```
if (list == null || list.size() == 0){
    Toast.makeText(this, "No stores", 5000).show();
    this.finish();  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside a fragment, you can keep a reference to `applicationContext` through `getActivity()` method.

```
Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); // Inside a fragment

Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_content), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

getActivity().finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Toast messages persist between `Activity`s, so all you should need to do is this:

```
@Override
onPause()
{
    Toast.makeToast("My text", Toast.length_long).show();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Something like that, though my variables names might be off a bit as I'm doing this off the top of my head :)